# Where can I get alerts for future delisting?

Tags: market-data

Suppose I have a large universe of US stocks and ETFs (3000). Is there any site where I can get free information for tickers that are delisting ?

E.g. recently:

(1) on 9/18/2015, Broadcom (BRCM) announced delisting for effective date 12/31/2016

(2) on 9/17/2015, Ryland Group (RYL) announced delisting for effective date 10/02/2015

(3) on 9/17/2015, Crestwood Midstream (CMLP) announced delisting for effective date 10/01/2015

I can parse websites too.

I'm just looking for information that becomes available on the same day or within 1-2 days of the announcement date (not around the effective date)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have this information freely available on [EDGAR](http://www.sec.gov/edgar.shtml). It is going to require some parsing and probably human verification (it's not a lot of data). You can query by filing type (i.e DEFM14A / DEFM14C for M&A).

** I'm not sure how accurate your examples are, for instance Broadcom's DEFM14A was filed on 9/28/2015, the M&A announcement was made on May/2015. Moreover (AFAIK), the effective delisting dates are uncertain.

Comment: thanks. this is really great. I don't need the actual delisting dates as much as I need to mark out these stocks for removal.

Comment: the better form is type 25 and 25-NSE, but unfortunately, vast majority of the filings are after the actual date of listing.